# Constant values in Apache IoTDB time series data: how to query?

Tags: constants, apache-iotdb, iotdb

How to query data in Apache IoTDB with constant in time series?

There is a constant data column in my time series of Apache IoTDB. When query using, such as "select status, '1' from root.ln.wf02.* align by device", an error will be reported "Constant operand is not allowed: "1" ", what is the reason? I tried both Version 0.13.3 and Version 1.0.0, and both reported this error. Is there any configuration that I need to change?

Does anyone can deal this problem？ Help please

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, Apache IoTDB currently cannot write constant column directly using "select" statement. If you really need this to be able to execute, you can go to github and update an issue to explain your query scenario on why you requires a separate constant column.